# gatsby-plugin-preact does not work with Gatsby 5+

Tags: gatsby, preact

I have **Gastby** 5.13.2 and I have installed `gatsby-plugin-preact` with `preact` and `react-render-to-string`. When I try to open a homepage in a dev mode I get an error:

```json
{
    "codeFrame": "No codeFrame could be generated",
    "sourcePosition": null,
    "sourceContent": null
}
```

in console I get

```bash
warn The path "/" errored during SSR.
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@rmwc/menu": "^14.0.7",
    "@rmwc/tabs": "^14.0.7",
    "classnames": "2.5.1",
    "common": "file:../common/",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "echarts": "^5.4.3",
    "echarts-for-react": "^3.0.2",
    "gatsby": "^5.13.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-env-variables": "^2.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-optimize-svgs": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-preact": "^7.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^6.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-canonical-urls": "^1.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-recaptcha": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes": "^4.19.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-s3": "^0.4.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^6.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^6.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-split-css": "^2.0.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2": "^1.1.32",
    "gatsby-source-drupal": "^6.13.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.13.1",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "parse-entities": "4.0.1",
    "preact": "^10.19.6",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.2.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-compare-slider": "3.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-html-parser": "2.0.2",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "1.2.6",
    "react-modal": "3.16.1",
    "react-player": "^2.14.1",
    "react-resize-detector": "6.7.0",
    "react-scroll": "1.9.0",
    "react-share": "5.0.3",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^3.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "swiper": "6.5.4",
    "typed.js": "^2.1.0",
    "universal-cookie": "4.0.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.48",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.11",
    "@types/react-html-parser": "2.0.6",
    "@types/react-infinite-scroller": "1.2.5",
    "@types/react-scroll": "1.8.10",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript-checker": "1.1.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "tsc-files": "^1.1.4",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  }
```

As for page, I've deleted almost everything and now it looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './homepage.scss';

const HomePage = () => <div>Test</div>;

export default function HomePageLanding(): React.ReactElement {
  return <HomePage />;
}
```

Without Preact everything works fine. Is there any solution for this error?

Comment: Your `package.json` references `"file:../common/"`. I'm not sure whether this is relevant but it would be good to know what's in that file. Alternatively (better!) could you just confirm that the issue persists when you remove this like from `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This project is monorepo, so common folder contains some common components. With React it works fine

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Can you share a complete (but minimal) setup which demonstrates this issue as a GitHub repository. Once we have figured out the issue we can delete the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that Preact is the source of the problem. I have the following set of packages on a **Gatsby** site and it works fine.

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "0.5.10",
    "asciidoctor": "2.2.6",
    "gatsby": "5.13.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "3.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "6.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "5.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "1.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "6.12.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "5.12.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-asciidoc": "4.12.0",
    "gatsby-adapter-netlify": "1.0.1",

    "gatsby-plugin-preact": "^7.13.1",
    "preact": "^10.19.6",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^6.4.0",

    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "slash": "1.0.0"
  }
```

The error indicates that the problem lies with the processing of your landing page (at path `/`). Can you please include a copy of the code for this page (probably something like `src/pages/index.js`)?

Using the code you provide in the updated question I am able to launch the site in development mode (see screenshot below). There must be something missing from your question that is required to trigger the problem. Could you please share a complete minimal example that shows the issue? You can just create a GitHub repository and share the link. This will be the quickest way to identify the problem without too much guesswork.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, I updated my question and included package.json and code of my page

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me some ideas. The problem was in a file called gatsby-config.js. There was a flag 'FAST_DEV: true', I just removed it and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Excellent. Glad that you resolved the issue. I did not know about the `FAST_DEV` option. Learned something new!